# How to password protect a single folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, debian, encryption, ubuntu-14.04

I need to password protect a single directory on Ubuntu.
1. The folder must be encrypted. 
2. Be easily accessed on a regular basis.
3. If possible, the folder should be portable.

How can I achieve this goal?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by portable?

Comment: Portable, as in I can move it to USB, other machine. But it's not a must.

Comment: Portable to what types of other systems? The first thing that comes to mind is encrypting the folder as a catch-all solution; the encryption key would be required to later unencrypt it and all that would be required on the other machine is the package to do so. How much data will be in this folder?

Comment: Do you need to be portable across operating systems? i.e. do you want to be able to open this on MS Windows?

Comment: @user2121874 no, just between other Debian based machines.

Comment: @sherrellbc the max size won't exceed 100MB

Comment: Okay, then use the DM-Crypt + Loopback solution that I linked to at the top of my answer.

Comment: @user2121874 Thank you. But I've decided to go with eCryptfs, it seem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ecryptfs works very well too.  install ecryptfs-utils first

instrucs here for debian, but will apply similarly.
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-and-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian/

I have 2 folders encrypted in this way

Pingers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it does **not** need to be portable across operating systems, then [this is probably what you are looking for](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-dm-crypt-to-create-an-encrypted-volume-on-an-ubuntu-vps). (DM-Crypt + Loopback File)

It is really trivial to create mount and unmount scripts for this kind of setup, that way you don't need to memorize all the steps to bring the encrypted folder online. Just make sure to remember to copy the scripts as well if you want to move the folder to another system.

If you really do need portability across Operating Systems, then [TrueCrypt v7.1.a is what you are looking for](https://github.com/AuditProject/truecrypt-verified-mirror?files=1). Make sure you get it from the verified mirror on GitHub, or you might be installing a Trojan. The reason why I don't recommend using this unless you absolutely need portability across Operating Systems is that there is [still some question as to whether or not TrueCrypt has been broken by the Feds](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/04/truecrypt_decrypted_by_fbi/).

Answer (score 0):

The venerable TrueCrypt has versions for most OS's, including [Linux distros](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-truecrypt-cli-on-linux) and Windows. It is simple to create a folder as a TrueCrypt container. *Caveat*: questions were rised about the trustworthiness of that encryption, and [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) *might* be an alternative, though I have seen no independent audit of VeraCrypt yet.

Another choice is simply to archive the folder with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or [PeaZip](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html) and use a password. Again, these applications are available for many OS's.

Comment: There have been updates to the TrucCrypt fiasco. Read the following:

http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/11/truecrypt-is-safer-than-previously-reported-detailed-analysis-concludes/
    ...    
http://www.howtogeek.com/203708/3-alternatives-to-the-now-defunct-truecrypt-for-your-encryption-needs/
    ...    
http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/

Comment: Though I would probably steer clear of it unless I absolutely needed portability across Operating Systems: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/04/truecrypt_decrypted_by_fbi/

Comment: Also, you should definitely prefer TrueCrypt v7.1.a over VeraCrypt as VeraCrypt has not had an independent audit (While TrueCrypt v7.1.a has had several).

Answer (score 0):

[EncFS](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/) is a good non-container (not a fixed size like TrueCrypt or dm-crypt/LUKS) **variable size** folder/file encryption system. It's available on any Debian system too.

Similar to eCryptFS, but EncFS **keeps it's config file inside the encrypted folder** and can be mounted rather "portably" and easily, whereas eCryptFS would require knowing the mount options or copying some extra config files to special folders before mounting.

Also EncFS **does not need root** privileges to run (like eCryptFS does), so EncFS is more "portable" running as a regular user only.